# button 'pay now!' not working for redirect to payment-done view in payment-braintree and django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am writing an online store based on the Django 3 By Example 3rd Edition book. I encountered a problem with the book's codes in the payment section, I searched the internet and updated some of the codes, but I still have a problem! After filling out the debit card form, when I click on
the "pay now!" button, I am not redirected to the Don page!

process.html

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}

{% block title %} Pay by credit card {% endblock %}

{% block sidenavigation %}

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    Pay by credit card

    

    
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
    {% if braintree_error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            {{ braintree_error|safe }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="braintree-notifications"></div>
    <div id="braintree-dropin"></div>
    <input style="background-color: #0783ca" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"
           type="button" value="Pay now!"/>
</form>

<script>
    var braintree_client_token = "{{ client_token}}";
    var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

    braintree.dropin.create({
        authorization: "{{client_token}}",
        container: '#braintree-dropin',
        card: {
            cardholderName: {
                required: false
            }
        }
    }, function (createErr, instance) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{% url "payment:process" %}',
                    data: {
                        'paymentMethodNonce': payload.nonce,
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    }
                }).done(function (result) {
                    //do accordingly
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

process view:

```
def payment_process(request):
"""The view that processes the payment"""
order_id = request.session.get('order_id')

order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)

total_cost = order.get_total_cost()
print(f'ORDER=== {order.first_name}')

if request.method == 'POST':
    print('---------Post------------')
    # retrieve nonce
    # retrieve nonce
    nonce = request.POST.get('paymentMethodNonce', None)

    # # create User
    customer_kwargs = {
        # "customer_id": order.braintree_id
        "first_name": order.first_name,
        "last_name": order.last_name,
        "email": order.email
    }
    customer_create = gateway.customer.create(customer_kwargs)
    customer_id = customer_create.customer.id

    # create and submit transaction

    result = gateway.transaction.sale({
        'amount': f'{total_cost:.2f}',
        'payment_method_nonce': nonce,
        'options': {
            'submit_for_settlement': True
        }
    })

    print(f'Result----{result}')
    if result.is_success:
        # mark the order as paid
        print(f'------Success----')

        order.paid = True

        # store the unique transaction id
        order.braintree_id = result.transaction.id
        order.save()

        return redirect('payment:done')
    else:
        return redirect('payment:canceled')
else:
    print('---------Get----------')
    # generate token
    client_token = gateway.client_token.generate()

    return render(
        request,
        'payment/process.html',
        {
            'order': order,
            'client_token': client_token
        }
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Your last image might suggest that jQuery is not loaded properly or after you're trying to call the ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

indent the code in the payment_process function

Comment: No no! Indent code in the project is correct. There is a problem here because of copy and paste :)